# Simple Graphics library not coloring lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph

I'm a student learning to program, and my current assignment is to write a graphing calculator using the Simple Graphics library. I got everything working, except for coloring the lines. The first line should be red, the second should be green and the third one blue, then they repeat. Here is the code I added for the colors:

```
if count % 3 == 1:
    print("red")
    setColor = ("red")
elif count % 3 == 2:
    print("green")
    setColor = ("green")
else:
    print("blue")
    setColor = ("blue")
```

Earlier in the code, I set count = 1 and at the end of my drawing loop, I have count = count + 1.

Whenever I try to use the program, all the lines appear black. When I look at the terminal, I see "red", "green" and "blue" all being printed successfully at the right times. Using RGB values to define the color doesn't help either.

Does anyone have any idea of what I could be doing wrong? I can post the entire code for drawing the lines, but I thought people wouldn't want to sift through 30 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setColor = ("color")` should just be `setColor("color")`. setColor is a function, that takes in input and performs an action. If it was a variable, which is just a name for some data that you will provide, your code would be correct. (Variables almost never have verbs in their names.)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!

Rookie mistakes I guess.